# TYPO3 TMENU in Bootstrap 3 thumbnail with panel list-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3, typoscript

I want to render a overviewsite in TYPO3 some kind of TMENU which isnt very easy. Relying on this HTML structure:

```html
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="headline">
        <h2>Headline</h2>
      </div>
      <img src="img/product/picture.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">              
         <div class="panel list-group">
           <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse-next">Menu 1</a>
             <div class="collapse list-group-submenu">
               <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 1</a>
               <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 2</a>
             </div>                        
           <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse-next">Menu 2</a>
             <div class="collapse list-group-submenu">
               <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 1</a>
               <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 2</a>
             </div>                            
           <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Menu 3</a>
           <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Menu 4</a>
           <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Menu 5</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>              
  </div>
```

The problem is now, that the main DIV isnt closed if there is no second navigation area. And im not able to insert a picture from mask which is assigned in the first level of the menu. Wrap cant insert any data. This is my actual poorly try. Are there any ideas here?

```html
# OVERVIEW MENU
lib.overviewmenu = HMENU
lib.overviewmenu {
        special = directory
        special.value.data = leveluid:2
  # erstes level
   1 = TMENU
   1.expAll = 1
   1 {
     # no state: normale Formatierung
     wrap =
     NO {
     
                 before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
                 before.cObject {
                         parentImage.cObject = IMAGE
                         parentImage.cObject.field = tx_mask_menuteaser
                 }    
     
     allWrap = <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><div class="headline"><h2>|  
     wrapItemAndSub = ||*|||*||
     #ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap {
             htmlSpecialChars = 0
             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
             crop = 50 | …
             }
     subst_elementUid = 1
     }
     
     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO

   }

         2 < .1
   2 {
     # no state: normale Formatierung
     wrap = </h2></div><img src="{register:parentImage}" alt=""><div class="caption"><div class="list-group">|</div></div></div></div>
     NO {
     allWrap =
     wrapItemAndSub = ||*|||*||
     #ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap {
             htmlSpecialChars = 0
             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
             crop = 50 | …
     }
     ATagParams = class="list-group-item"
     subst_elementUid = 1
     }

     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO
     
     IFSUB = 1
                 IFSUB {
                         #ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                         stdWrap {
                      wrap = |<i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                      wrap.insertData = 1              
                             htmlSpecialChars = 0
                             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
                             crop = 50 | …
                   }
                   ATagParams = class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse-next"
             subst_elementUid = 1                              
            }
           
     ACTIFSUB = 1
                 ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB        

   }
   
         3 < .2
   3 {
     # no state: normale Formatierung
     wrap = <div class="list-group-submenu collapse">|</div>
     NO {
     allWrap =
     linkWrap = <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>&nbsp;|
     wrapItemAndSub = ||*|||*||
     ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap {
             htmlSpecialChars = 0
             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
             crop = 50 | …
     }
     ATagParams = class="list-group-item sub-item small"
     subst_elementUid = 1
     }

     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO      

   }  

}
```

Thanks and best, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got it:

```html
# OVERVIEW MENU
lib.overviewmenu = HMENU
lib.overviewmenu {
        special = directory
        special.value.data = leveluid:2
  # erstes level
   1 = TMENU
   1.expAll = 1
   1 {
     # no state: normale Formatierung
     NO {
     
                 after.cObject = COA
                 after.cObject {
                                               
                          10 = FILES
                                10 {  
                                  references {    
                                  table = pages    
                                  uid.field = uid    
                                  fieldName = tx_mask_menuteaser  
                                  }  

                                  renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE  
                                  renderObj {    
                                    file.import.data = file:current:uid    
                                    file.treatIdAsReference = 1    
                                    stdWrap.wrap= <img src='|' />  
                                    }
                                   
                                  }
                                 
                 }  
     
     linkWrap = <div class="headline"><h2>|</h2></div>
     wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail">|</div></div>|*|<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail">|</div></div>|*|<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail">|</div></div>
     stdWrap {
             htmlSpecialChars = 0
             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
             crop = 50 | …
             }
     subst_elementUid = 1
     }
     
     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO

   }

         2 < .1
   2 {
     # no state: normale Formatierung
     wrap = <div class="caption"><div class="list-group">|</div></div>
     NO {
     linkWrap =
     allWrap =
     wrapItemAndSub = ||*|||*||
     #ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap {
             htmlSpecialChars = 0
             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
             crop = 50 | …
     }
     ATagParams = class="list-group-item"
     subst_elementUid = 1
     }

     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO
     
     IFSUB = 1
                 IFSUB {
                         #ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                         stdWrap {
                      wrap = |<i class="fa fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                      wrap.insertData = 1              
                             htmlSpecialChars = 0
                             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
                             crop = 50 | …
                   }
                   ATagParams = class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse-next"
             subst_elementUid = 1                              
            }
           
     ACTIFSUB = 1
                 ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB        

   }
   
         3 < .2
   3 {
     # no state: normale Formatierung
     wrap = <div class="list-group-submenu collapse">|</div>
     NO {
     allWrap =
     linkWrap = <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>&nbsp;|
     wrapItemAndSub = ||*|||*||
     ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap {
             htmlSpecialChars = 0
             htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 0
             crop = 50 | …
     }
     ATagParams = class="list-group-item sub-item small"
     subst_elementUid = 1
     }

     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO      

   }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*ouch* very unbalanced code.

try to get the wraps closed where you open it.
Use `before` and `after`.

Otherwise be aware of `IFSUB` on top level. if you close a tag in the next menu level, you should only open it if you are sure to have a next level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hmmm, very strange. But where do i have to place before and after? 

The problem is the wrapping point for all the parts in the second menu level. They are on a other place then the first level wrapping. This is confusing me...

Comment: if you want to understand all the wrapping (look into TSRef for a complete list of wraps. https://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/476/ shows all wraps in one example. in the same way you can configure all wraps and remove those wraps you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

**Your html like this.**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="headline">
        <h2>Headline</h2>
      </div>
      <img src="img/product/picture.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">              
         <!-- Add menu typoscript here -->
      </div>
   </div>              
</div>
```

**And your typoscript LIke this.**

```
lib.mainmenu = TMENU
lib.mainmenu{
  expAll = 1
  wrap = <div class="panel list-group">|</div>
  NO{
    ATagParams = class="list-group-item"
  }

  ACT = 1
  ACT {
    linkWrap= <li class="active">|</li>
  }

   IFSUB < .NO
   IFSUB = 1
   IFSUB {
       wrapItemAndSub = <div class="collapse list-group-submenu">|</div>
       ATagParams = class="list-group-item sub-item small"
       stdWrap.wrap = <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> |
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pravin, 

thanks a lot for your idea. But this isnt working for me at all, because i have to fill out the <h2>Headline</h2> with the root navigation title. And there are lots of thumbnail boxes, depending on the count of root elements. 

Last but not least there is to render the image ressource, which is in the media section of the root navigation page or assigned via mask file relation.

Answer (score 0):

Whats about this html structure? Would be much easier, isnt it?

```
                   <div class="panel list-group thumbnail">
                     <div class="headline"><h2>Headline</h2></div>
                     <img src="img/product/picture.jpg" alt="...">
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse-next">Page 1</a>
                       <div class="collapse list-group-submenu">
                         <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 1</a>
                         <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 2</a>
                       </div>                        
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse-next">Page 2</a>
                       <div class="collapse list-group-submenu">
                         <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 1</a>
                         <a class="list-group-item sub-item small"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> Submenu 2</a>
                       </div>                            
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Page 3</a>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Page 4</a>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Page 5</a>
                   </div>
```